# Xamarin XCT Media Element not playing recorded audio on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using the AudioRecorder [Plugin](https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder) to record audio and then save it / play it back using the XCT Media element control.

Working fine on iPhone, however on Android it's not playing back the audio at all - either locally or from a URL.

I've taken a copy of the Xamarin sample project (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/MediaElementDemos) and replaced the URL in the PlayWebAudioPage with the link to my recorded Audio file and it just doesn't play on Android.

Any ideas on how to investigate this further / fix?

The file plays fine on iPhone, on the computer web browser, VLC etc.

Comment: AudioRecorder has not been updated in 4 years and only supports `wav` files.  Have you tried playing other wav files in Android to see if it supports them?  See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

Comment: I've had success playing sounds with [Simple Audio Player](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer/).

Comment: Is there any alternative to using AudioRecorder plugin @Jason ?